# Why $\Bbb Z\cap (a+b\sqrt{-7})=(a^2+7b^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Could you tell me why $\Bbb Z\cap (a+b\sqrt{-7})=(a^2+7b^2)$ holds?

⊇ is obvious, but the other direction ⊆ is not obvious to me..
How can I check ⊆ ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In what ring are you working?

Comment: It’s not true unless $\gcd(a,b)=1.$

Comment: I’m working in a ring Z[√ー７].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(c+d \sqrt{m})(a+ b\sqrt{m})\in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow c b + d a = 0$. Let's assume moreover that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then since $c b = - d a$,  we get  $a\mid c$, so $c = k a$, and from above (assume $a\ne 0$, at least one of $a$, $b$ is $\ne 0$), $d = -k b$. Therefore $(c+ d\sqrt{m}) = k (a - b\sqrt{m})$, and so
$$(c+d \sqrt{m})(a+ b\sqrt{m}) = k ( a^2 - m b^2)$$